# What is the best practice for creating custom UIView's?

Tags: ios, uiview

For creating custom views i have three options.

1. Override

   func drawRect(_ rect: CGRect)
2. Add sub-layers to the view's Layer.
3. Do both.

What is the best practice? why would i override drawRect if i can draw everything in a sub-layer (With an easier API)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rendering in `drawRect` means that you are using the CPU to draw your view using Core Graphics.

If you can use a composition of `CALayer` sub-layers, then that is almost always the better option as the heavy lifting is then done by GPU.

On top of that, `drawRect` is called on the main thread, and if your drawing code isn't fast your app will be less responsive (of course you can use a background thread to solve this problem, but you will still be using the CPU to draw your bitmap).

Comment: I agree with Clafou, for the reasons he outlines. Avoid using drawRect if you can. It tends to be the least efficient way of drawing. Sublayers and subviews are almost always faster.